# Specified cast is not valid when reading a Float column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Well I am stuck... again. Everything was sailing smooth until now. I am reading some data from the DB (something usual) but its giving me the specified cast is not valid error. Its not the first time I've dealt with this error; earlier on I had it with a date column. Anyway, I have a table that I need to read. Its data type is FLOAT. so this is the code I am using:

```
Dim rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
While rdr.Read
    theResults.Add(New UserData With {
        .BalAvailable = rdr.GetFloat(0),
        .branch = rdr.GetInt32(1)
     })
End While
```

This is running under a function; this is the Class...

```
Class UserData
    Dim theResults = New List(Of UserData)

    Property Branch As Integer
    Property BalAvailable As Single

End Class
```

And this is the input part...

```
Dim clientNo As Integer = 0
Dim myResults = GetData(clientNo)
If Integer.TryParse(txtInput.Text, clientNo) Then
    If myResults.Count = 1 Then
        txtBalAvail.Text = CInt(myResults(0).BalAvail)
    Else
```

Everytime I input a value it gives me the specified cast is not valid error.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +5270501
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i) +62
```

I believe this could be related to the statements I use?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
```

I am stuck. I also tried changing the rdr.GetFloat to Double, and in Integer.TryParse to Double.TryParse. I am so stuck!

Comment: Value isn't NULL either

Comment: When you tried `Double.TryParse` did you also change `clientNo` to double? And why would you want to cast a FLOAT as an INT in the first place?

Comment: It is not clear to me what line is generating the error, is it .branch = rdr.GetInt32(1)? You are showing code reading user input and code reading from the DB, how are they both relevant? What is the full error message?

Comment: PatfromCanada..... VStudio shows the whole sqlCommand reader area as the problem. I showed the code of input because that's basically what calls the reader part. I beleive its the .BalAvailable = rdr.GetDouble since that reading code is what Ive been using flawlessly for a while now\

Comment: MikeSmith I tried your suggestion of changing clientNo to see if it worked and no go. As for the variable mistake I fixed that to Dim BalAvailable as Double to see if that fixed the issue to no avail

Comment: Look at `rdr.GetFieldType(0)` - if it's not `System.Single`, you can't read it with the `GetFloat` method.

Comment: **NB:** A SQL data-type of `float` doesn't correspond to a .NET `Float` / `Single`; the type will be `Double`, so you'll need to use `rdr.GetDouble(0)` to read it.

Comment: Changed to rdr.GetDouble(0)... same error.

Comment: Then the first column of your resultset isn't a SQL `float`. What does the `rdr.GetFieldType(0)` return?

Comment: Hang on - your stack trace is for `GetInt32`, which is the **second** column. What does `rdr.GetFieldType(1)` return?

Comment: Freaking Jackpot Richard Deeming. It was a NChar data type; I changed it to GetValue and the program didn't blow in my face this time. The code didn't work as well as I thought though... the textbox I have should display a value (1.11) and instead its displaying only 1. Gotta check into that; but at least the main error has gone away. Can you make your comment an answer so I can mark it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: And the "1" error was because I had a "CINT" command. Its fixed now. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strongly-typed `Get...` methods (`GetFloat`, `GetInt32`, etc.) will only work if the data-type of the field is an exact match.

Use the `GetFieldType` method to examine the real data-type of the field, and either use the appropriate strongly-typed `Get...` method, or the untyped `GetValue` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="BILLTOTAL" DataFormatString="{0:n}" 
                            HeaderText="BILL TOTAL" />

  decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("BILLTOTAL"));
 GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = total.ToString("N2");
```